# Class not found for UIMA pear fle

Tags: uima

I am new in UIMA. I am working with pear files for annotation purposes from PubMed xml file. I have already installed Julie Lab medline reader UIMA collection reader file and Lingpipe gazeteer as analysis engine. I have run CPE generator and tried to get proper annotated words, but I failed to do that. The following error occurred:

`The class de.julielab.jules.reader.reader.MedlineReader could not be found
Descripotor file=file/C:/apache-uima/examples/descriptor/collection reader/julie-medline-reader 1.7/desc/Medlinereaderdesciptor.xml
causedBy: org.apache.uima.ResourceInitializationException:The class de.julielab.jules.reader.reader.MedlineReader could not be found`

`caused by: Java.lang.classNotFound exception
de.julielab.jules.reader.reader.MedlineReader`

It would be a great help to me to give me a solution to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the MedlineReader CollectionReader descriptor in your PEAR at

```
C:/apache-uima/examples/descriptor/collection reader/julie-medline-reader 1.7/desc/Medlinereaderdesciptor.xml
```

and look at the typesystem imports:

```
 <typeSystemDescription>
  <imports>
    <import location="julie-document-meta-pubmed-types.xml"/>
    <import location="julie-document-structure-types.xml"/>
  </imports>
</typeSystemDescription>
```

make sure that these files exists. Try to hardcode the full path (something like C:/....) and see if that fixes the problem.

PS: beware that you have spaces in your paths, better use underscores

```
C:/apache-uima/examples/descriptor/collection_reader/julie-medline-reader_1.7/desc/Medlinereaderdesciptor.xml
```